# Proving that Breadth-First Search (BFS) results in a bipartition of a tree

Tags: graphs, trees, graph-traversal, breadth-first-search

In my studies of discrete mathematics, I've learned that a tree graph is inherently bipartite. I'm interested in finding an algorithmic approach to determine its bipartition. It seems to me that Breadth-First Search (BFS) could be a reasonable method for this task.

However, I'm struggling with the formal proof of this concept. Could anyone provide a detailed explanation or proof showing that applying BFS to a tree will indeed result in a valid bipartition? Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be an arbitrary root.

Denote by $d(v)$ the distance from $r$ to $v$. As you might know, every edge goes either between vertices of the same layer, ie, vertices of same $d(v)$, or between vertices in consecutive layers.

Now, there cannot be an edge going from one vertex in layer $\ell$ to another vertex in layer $\ell$ because then we would have a cycle of length $2\ell+1$, hence every edge goes between consecutive layers.

Let $L$ be the set of vertices with even $d(v)$ and $R$ the ones with odd $d(v)$.

It follows that there are no edges inside neither $L$ nor $R$.